# Npm: Run postinstall script only when installed as dependency

Tags: npm, babeljs, npm-scripts

I developed a npm package ("node_commons") which is included in my other project like this:

package.json (other project)

```
"node-commons": "git+ssh://git@stash.custom.domain.net:7999/npm/libs/node_commons.git"
```

The node_commons package is written in ES6 but this version is not supported later, therefore I use a postinstall script to transpile it with babel.

package.json (node_commons)

```
"postinstall": "babel src -d src"
```

This works fine. When the package is included as dependency in my project, the files are transpiled.

My problem: When I develop the node_commons package I use `npm install` to install the internal dependencies. But then I do not want to transpile it. **I only want to transpile, when the package is installed as dependency** (e.g. in my other project). Is there a way to do this?

Something like this:

package.json (node_commons)

```
"postinstall-as-dependency": "babel src -d src"
```

Comment: I was wondering the same thing. This is ridiculous. There should be two different lifecycle hooks for these two scenarios because they are completely different tasks.

Answer (score 8):

- Create `.no-postinstall` file in module root.
- **Mac & Linux:** Add following to `package.json`: `"postinstall": "if [ ! -e .no-postinstall ]; then babel src -d src; fi"`
- **Windows:** Add following to `package.json`: `"postinstall": if exist .no-postinstall () else (babel src -d src)"`
- **Cross Platform (more work):**
  You can create a node script (i.e. `./my-script.js`) and using `fs` module, check existence of `.no-postinstall` and execute `babel src -d src` using `child_process.exec()` as described in [official doc here](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback). Add your script to `package.json`: `"postinstall": node my-script.js`

Please note that I use Mac, so I can't verify Windows version.

#### Explanation

`if [ ! -e .no-postinstall ]` checks non-existence (with negation operator `!`) of given file. If file does not exist, it executes your script. Since you add `.no-postinstall` file to your module root, script does not get executed when you install your internal modules. On the other hand, modules installing your module as a dependency do not have `.no-postinstall` file in their root and your script get executed.

`.no-postinstall` is not a special name, you can use whatever name you choose.

Comment: it's no use. because npm script always runs with package root as its CWD. https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/commands/npm-run-script

Comment: Just add it to `.npmignore` then. It will work better like that than as originally posted.

Answer (score 5):

In my case, I had a postinstall script that I only wanted to run when the package was NOT installed as a dependency.

Here is the `package.json` script I used:

```
{
    [...]
    "scripts": {
        "@comment_postinstall": "Behavior of the node-js subscript below: if '.git' doesn't exist under my-lib, it's installed as a dep, so do nothing -- else, return error-code 1, causing patch-package to run.",
        "postinstall": "node -e \"let myLibAsDep = !require('fs').existsSync('.git'); if (!myLibAsDep) process.exit(1);\" || patch-package"
    },
    [...]
}
```

You can of course just reverse the `if (!myLibAsDep)` if you want your script to run only when installed as a dependency.

Answer (score 4):

If I understand correctly, you want your package to run a `postinstall` script only if user install it as a dependency (`npm install node-common`)?

When your postinstall script runs, it has the `npm_config_save_dev` available to it, which is 'true' when users install the package with the `--save-dev` flag:

```
"postinstall": "! [ $npm_config_save_dev ] && echo \"Installed as a dependency\" || \"Installed as a dev dependency\""
```

Answer (score 3):

This should do the trick:

```js
if (process.env.INIT_CWD === process.cwd())
  process.exit()
```

Works with npm and pnpm. Don't know about yarn

https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/using-npm/scripts#best-practices

Comment: This is the best technique presented so far: it does not rely on any files in the package, doesn't rely on node_modules, doesn't rely on git. Will always work in all cases.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, I had a postinstall script which I wanted to run only when the package is installed as a dependency.

At the top of my postinstall script I added:

```js
if (!process.cwd().includes('node_modules')) {
 return;
}
```

and then it only ran when the module existed under a `node_modules` dir.

Comment: Can work in most cases, but I assume some cases would fail. (eg. if there a dependency under the parent project as well as under your lib, and the versions are incompatible, then your lib will have its own `node_modules` folder for it, even when your lib is installed as a dependency) That said, you can modify the if-statement to check for a specific dependency of your lib that you know the parent project will never have, and that thus would only be under your lib when your lib is not installed as a dependency.

Comment: I found an even better way: just check for the existence of a `.git` folder in your lib's directory. If it doesn't exist, it means your lib is installed as a dependency (well, assuming you're using git when developing your library -- which is nearly everyone I reckon). Full solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68915638/2441655

Answer (score 0):

I created a package to solve this problem, inspired by the answer from [@venryx](https://sss).

https://github.com/douglasjunior/ignore-dependency-scripts

### Usage

Replace this:

```json
  // package.json

  "name": "my-library",
  "scripts:" { 
    // "start", "test", "build", etc
    "postinstall/preinstall/prepare/etc": "your && scripts && here"
  },
```

With this:

```json
  // package.json

  "name": "my-library",
  "scripts:" { 
    // "start", "test", "build", etc
    "postinstall/preinstall/prepare/etc": "npx --yes ignore-dependency-scripts \"your && scripts && here\""
  },
```

> Replace `your && scripts && here` by any post/pre install script that you want, like `husky install`, `npx pod-install` or both.

Now, when you run `yarn install` or `npm install` in `./my-library` the `your && scripts && here` will run normally.

But, when you install `my-library` as a dependency (aka `yarn add url/to/my-library.git`) in another repository, the `your && scripts && here` will be ignored.