# Is there a way to run `postinstall` only when installing locally and not when being installed as a dependency?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, package.json, post-install

I wanted to run `postinstall` only when installing locally and not when my package is being installed as a dependency.

For example, `x` has a post install script and `y` has the dependency `x`. I want to run it when running `npm install` inside `x` and not when the packages are being installed for `y`. Is there a good way to do this?

Comment: you can find a solution here 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54212147/npm-run-postinstall-script-only-when-installed-as-dependency